# boolean algebra in SQL

Tags: sql, boolean, algebra

I need to convert the following C statement to SQL query.

```
if((object->num1 == 10 && object->num2 == 11) || (object->num3 == 0 && object->num4 == 1)){
//something
}
```

I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (conditions here)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: TRY `SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE (num1 =10 AND num2 =11) OR (num3 = 0 AND num4 = 1);` here num1,num2,num3,num4 are column names.

Comment: `where (num1, num2) = (10,11) or (num3, num4) = (0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE (num1=10 AND num2=11) OR (num3=0 AND num4=1);
```